# What is the effect of grouping some of the target classes on Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, boosting

Suppose that the target variable consists of `n` distinct classes. Suppose also that the goal is to maximize the accuracy (F-score) of the specific class, say `i`.

What will be the effect of grouping some of the remaining target classes on prediction accuracy? The variables can be grouped because of either the insufficient sample size or because they are very similar within the constructed groups.

Thank you,

Best regards

Comment: accuracy and f-score are not the same thing... and if you create your confusion matrix, grouping is just summing some rows and columns, so I don't think it will have any effect

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I mean grouping before running the model. So, it probably has effect on result. Thank you, I know that F-score and accuracy are not the same thing.